# React Native opens to white screen in Android simulator

Tags: android, react-native

I created a new default project with React Native `0.60.4` and it opens ok in the iOS simulator, but when trying to open it on Android by selecting the project directory and then `npm start`, `react-native run-android` it opens to a white screen.

Then shortly after it returns an error message in the android emulator saying:

`Unable to load script. Make sure you're either running a Metro server (run 'react-native start') or that your bundle is packaged correctly for release.`

The Android simulator is working fine with Flutter so there should be no problem. I looked at other solutions for this issue and they say run `react-native start` first but I most certainly have done.

Answer (score 0):

First run `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081` on your terminal
You can find it in `~/Library/Android/sdk/platform_tools/`

If that's not working please check your host ip and port on developer menu on android.
It can cause the issue on your side.

Comment: I've got android-23, android-27, android-28 and android-29 in that folder. React Native's target is 28. I couldn't find an `abd` file in there though. I'm on Mac btw, I should have mentioned in my question.

Comment: Inside Android sdk folder, there should be `platform_tools` folder.
Inside there, you can find adb file.
Once you locate it, then run `./adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081`

Comment: I ran the abd command but it said no device emulators found, so I opened the android emulator and then it ran ok. But it didn't fix the error, still the white screen.

Comment: Is it loading the jsbundle from metro bundler?
Do you get any error on there?

Comment: Yes it throws the error as above in the question if I wait about 30 seconds. The app runs fine on iOS as detailed in the question.